# How can I know that plt.colorbar must "eat" ax.pcolor?

Tags: matplotlib

Consider the following code:

```
#%%
Z=np.random.rand(len(X),len(Y))
X=np.arange(0,10)
Y=np.arange(0,10)

[fig1,ax1]=plt.subplots()
pcm=ax1.pcolor(X,Y,Z,cmap='seismic',edgecolors='black')
plt.colorbar(pcm,extend='max')

#[fig1,ax1]=plt.subplots()
#ax1.pcolor(X,Y,Z,cmap='seismic',edgecolors='black')
#plt.colorbar(extend='max')
```

The uncommented part works while the commented one doesnt. The error returned being:

> RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).

Looking [at the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html), it is said:

> The matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable (i.e., Image, ContourSet, etc.)
> described by this colorbar. This argument is mandatory for the
> Figure.colorbar method but optional for the pyplot.colorbar function,
> which sets the default to the current image.

In this case, pcm correspond to the return value of ax1.pcolor() which type is "matplotlib.collections.Collection" and doesn't appear in the (non exhaustive) list given by the documentation.

How could I know from the documentation that I would indeed have to provide to plt.colorbar ax1.pcolor ? I know this from a stackoverflow post. How could I guess this from reading at the documentation ?

Comment: because `pcolor` is not used very much (most people use `pcolormesh`.  But the documentation in matplotlib is written by volunteers, so if you had a suggested improvement, I'm sure a PR would be welcome.

Comment: @JodyKlymak hello. Thank for the comment. Even for pcolormesh it is not clear that we should provide what pcolormesh returns to colorbar. So in the end I guess the answer is that the documentation is not complete.

Comment: Again, you are welcome too suggest improvements.  However, directly under the documentation you link there is a list of over 10 examples that show the usage...